# using bracket notation for reading json in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a requirement where I have to read the value of the JSON data for the column which user passes

```
for (var k = 0; k < arr.length; k++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < checkedFilters.length; i++) {
        console.log("value[columnName]", arr[k][columnName]);
        if ((arr[k][columnName] == checkedFilters[i])) {
            temporaryFilterData.push(arr[k]);
        }
    }
}
```

`columnName` will be passed by the user in a function
but when ever I try to log the value of `arr[k][columnName]`, it only gives me the very first value of the array.
What is the possible reason

JSON

```
 [
        {
            id: 1,
            type: 1,
            typeName: "Lead",
            client: 1,
            clientName: "Ljungbloms Elektriska AB",
            marking: "Marking for Ljungbloms Elektriska AB",
            status: 2,
            statusName: "Open",
            stage: 2,
            stageName: "Stage 2",
            leadValue: 1,
            probability: 1,
            issuer: 1,
            issuerName: "Sales",
            handler: 1,
            handlerName: "Sales",
            created: 1462345200000,
            createdString: "2016-05-04"
        },
        {
            id: 5,
            type: 1,
            typeName: "Lead",
            client: 1,
            clientName: "Ljungbloms Elektriska AB",
            marking: "Marking for Ljungbloms Elektriska AB",
            status: 2,
            statusName: "Open",
            stage: 2,
            stageName: "Stage 2",
            leadValue: 1,
            probability: 1,
            issuer: 1,
            issuerName: "Sales",
            handler: 1,
            handlerName: "Sales",
            created: 1462345200000,
            createdString: "2016-05-04"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            type: 1,
            typeName: "Lead",
            client: 2,
            clientName: "Solina Sweden AB",
            marking: "Marking for Solina Sweden AB",
            status: 1,
            statusName: "Closed",
            stage: 3,
            stageName: "Stage 3",
            leadValue: 1,
            probability: 1,
            issuer: 1,
            issuerName: "Sales",
            handler: 1,
            handlerName: "Sales",
            created: 1462345200000,
            createdString: "2016-05-04"
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            type: 2,
            typeName: "Opportunity",
            client: 3,
            clientName: "H & M Hennes & Mauritz GBC AB",
            marking: "Marking for H & M Hennes & Mauritz GBC AB",
            status: 3,
            statusName: "Pending",
            stage: 4,
            stageName: "Stage 4",
            leadValue: 1,
            probability: 1,
            issuer: 1,
            issuerName: "Sales",
            handler: 1,
            handlerName: "Sales",
            created: 1462345200000,
            createdString: "2016-05-04"
        }
     ];
```

**checkedFileter Array**

```
["Open", "Unset","Closed"]
```

**result JSON**

```
[{
                id: 1,
                type: 1,
                typeName: "Lead",
                client: 1,
                clientName: "Ljungbloms Elektriska AB",
                marking: "Marking for Ljungbloms Elektriska AB",
                status: 2,
                statusName: "Open",
                stage: 2,
                stageName: "Stage 2",
                leadValue: 1,
                probability: 1,
                issuer: 1,
                issuerName: "Sales",
                handler: 1,
                handlerName: "Sales",
                created: 1462345200000,
                createdString: "2016-05-04"
            },
            {
                id: 5,
                type: 1,
                typeName: "Lead",
                client: 1,
                clientName: "Ljungbloms Elektriska AB",
                marking: "Marking for Ljungbloms Elektriska AB",
                status: 2,
                statusName: "Open",
                stage: 2,
                stageName: "Stage 2",
                leadValue: 1,
                probability: 1,
                issuer: 1,
                issuerName: "Sales",
                handler: 1,
                handlerName: "Sales",
                created: 1462345200000,
                createdString: "2016-05-04"
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                type: 1,
                typeName: "Lead",
                client: 2,
                clientName: "Solina Sweden AB",
                marking: "Marking for Solina Sweden AB",
                status: 1,
                statusName: "Closed",
                stage: 3,
                stageName: "Stage 3",
                leadValue: 1,
                probability: 1,
                issuer: 1,
                issuerName: "Sales",
                handler: 1,
                handlerName: "Sales",
                created: 1462345200000,
                createdString: "2016-05-04"
            }]
```

**ColumnName** is a variable, you can understand it as a simple variable holding name of the column
ex: `statusName`

So this should work like, the condition will check for the statusName only.
ie..loop should now check Json element statusName

Comment: In that case, please show the relevant section of that `JSON` also.

Comment: @Rohit416 updated with json

Comment: where do you get `columnName` and please add an example of `checkedFilters`.

Comment: @Rohit416 , @ Nina Scholz updated queston

Comment: You are logging value of `arr[k][columnName]` outside of `if` condition. It will be logged each time loop will run.

Comment: @SachinGupta its not an issue, my problem is this is not working as expect

Comment: actually, you get only one element as result. should there be more?

Comment: I have tried your code, and it is is working as expected. Filtering Array according to checkedFileterArray value

Comment: @NinaScholz, result array should come according to the JSON.it can be multiple also.For in this case if column name is "statusName" and we check for open"", then it should return 2 objects.

Comment: i see only one with `'Open'`.

Comment: @SachinGupta, how actually you did, beacuse arr[k][columnName] gives only same old value everytime

Comment: @NinaScholz , i am very sorry, yes for in this case only one will come,

Comment: See the JSON you have posted contains only one Object with 'Open' status name

Comment: @nina but multiple rows can also come if it check for pending or open,depending on array.

Comment: I have modified your JSON to include two `Open` json objects and its working as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a bit more suited array methods, like [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), because you need only iterate for the test until a value is found and the result set is just a subset of the given array.

```js
var arr = [{ id: 1, type: 1, typeName: "Lead", client: 1, clientName: "Ljungbloms Elektriska AB", marking: "Marking for Ljungbloms Elektriska AB", status: 2, statusName: "Open", stage: 2, stageName: "Stage 2", leadValue: 1, probability: 1, issuer: 1, issuerName: "Sales", handler: 1, handlerName: "Sales", created: 1462345200000, createdString: "2016-05-04" }, { id: 5, type: 1, typeName: "Lead", client: 1, clientName: "Ljungbloms Elektriska AB", marking: "Marking for Ljungbloms Elektriska AB", status: 2, statusName: "Open", stage: 2, stageName: "Stage 2", leadValue: 1, probability: 1, issuer: 1, issuerName: "Sales", handler: 1, handlerName: "Sales", created: 1462345200000, createdString: "2016-05-04" }, { id: 2, type: 1, typeName: "Lead", client: 2, clientName: "Solina Sweden AB", marking: "Marking for Solina Sweden AB", status: 1, statusName: "Closed", stage: 3, stageName: "Stage 3", leadValue: 1, probability: 1, issuer: 1, issuerName: "Sales", handler: 1, handlerName: "Sales", created: 1462345200000, createdString: "2016-05-04" }, { id: 3, type: 2, typeName: "Opportunity", client: 3, clientName: "H & M Hennes & Mauritz GBC AB", marking: "Marking for H & M Hennes & Mauritz GBC AB", status: 3, statusName: "Pending", stage: 4, stageName: "Stage 4", leadValue: 1, probability: 1, issuer: 1, issuerName: "Sales", handler: 1, handlerName: "Sales", created: 1462345200000, createdString: "2016-05-04" }],
    checkedFilters = ["Open", "Unset", "Closed"],
    columnName = 'statusName',
    temporaryFilterData = arr.filter(function (a) {
        return checkedFilters.some(function (b) {
            return a[columnName] == b;
        });
    });

console.log(temporaryFilterData);
```

Comment: but this will only return one single row. I have updated my JSON. Whereever it gets a match it should add that row to a array iist

Comment: actually I am working on filtering. and ["Open", "Unset","Closed"] are the checkboxes

Comment: yes, but what is wrong with the single row? what do you expect?

Comment: for this  ["Open", "Unset","Closed"],  it should return 3 row, because we can find 3 objects in statusName.

Comment: so if you find one out of three, you like to get the same element three times (as the length of `checkedFilters`)?

Comment: actually, we are checking for this ["Open", "Unset","Closed"] .I have updated my JSON.Now i should get 2 objects for open and one object for closed.Hope you got it this time

Comment: it would be easier, if you include the wanted content of `temporaryFilterData`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115104/discussion-between-abhishek-asthana-and-nina-scholz).